# Get parent of Product by ID

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to get a Product with his parent by product ID and I have this code:

```php
/**
 * @param string[] $ids
 * @return ProductCollection|EntityCollection
 */
public function getProductsByIds(array $ids): ProductCollection
{
    $criteria = new Criteria($ids);
    $criteria->addAssociation('parent');

    return $this->productRepository
        ->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())
        ->getEntities();
}
```

But the problem is when I'm running this code:

```php
$products = $this->productService->getProductsByIds([$id]);
$product = $products->first();
dd($product->getParent());
```

I'm getting `null` every time.

How can I get a Product parent and where can I read more about the 'paths' for the Association method?

Comment: The code looks good to me. Are you sure that the first product you load has a parent?

Comment: Hi @j_elfering. Yes, I'm sure. I've double-checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 6.3.4.0 version of Shopware, I'm getting the error 400 now.

> It is not possible to read the parent association directly. Please read the parents via a separate call over the repository

So I have removed Association and created a separate method to fetch *one* Product with a parent.

```php
public function getProductById(?string $id): ?ProductEntity
{
    if ($id === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $products = $this->getProductsByIds([$id]);
    $product = $products->first();
    $parentProductId = $product?->getParentId() ?? null;
    $parentProduct = $this->getProductById($parentProductId);

    if ($parentProduct !== null) {
        $product->setParent($parentProduct);
    }

    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your method you get EntityCollection, and not Single entity as result. So you should use the following code:

```
$products = $this->productService->getProductByIds([$id]);
foreach($products as $product) {
    dd($product->getParent());
}
```

And make sure that your products have parents of course:)

Comment: Yes, I've put the wrong execution code... I'll edit it.